# How to use android material theme in QtWidgets

Tags: android, c++, qt, qtwidgets

I'm creating a mobile app with QtWidgets (C++) and I've remarked that the app looks like android old apps:

[image]

but when I make a test with Qt Quick, the look and feel is completely different and more modern:

[image]

but I don't want to use qml.

I have seen that I could modify the AndroidManifest.xml file as :

```xml
<manifest ...>
  <application ... android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
    ...
  </application>
  ...
</manifest>
```

but it doesn't work

Is there a way to have a more modern look and feel for my qt c++ android app ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this file **qtquickcontrols2.conf** in your resources.

Please take a look in the Qt [Docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-material.html) and [Style](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html#using-styles-in-qt-quick-controls)

Comment: I am working on a qt widgets based project, not qt quick. I don't think `QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material")` will work. I was asking if there is a way to have a material theme like for android qt widgets based projects

Comment: QWidget don't support Material Design. So You should implement this Material design by yourself.

Comment: It means that I will have to deal with this look. Thanks

Comment: Yep you have to make it by yourself. QWidget is a bit old concept

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the impression that the Qt widgets-based implementation of the Material Design specification provided by https://github.com/laserpants/qt-material-widgets could be exactly what you are looking for?

I have not used this myself so I can not give concrete feedback on the usability. But the look and feel from the videos in the repository look very "attractive" in the sense that they appear to have a modern, clean look that resembles what a "modern" application may look like still in 2022.

It would be interesting if you can confirm that this is useful, or what you eventually ended up using?